# Replace String with character code in Java

Tags: java, string

Can't figure out how to replace a string with a character in Java. I wanted a function like this:

```
replace(string, char)
```

but there's not a function like this in Java.

```
String    str = str.replace("word",  '\u0082');
String    str = str.replace("word",  (char)130);
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Why not just make the `char` a String? Example: `str.replace("word",  "" + '\u0130');`

Comment: @40-love ,James Taylor is right. You can do task my converting char to String.  Or If you have special requirement then please let me know your use case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way:

```
"value_".replace("_",String.valueOf((char)58 )); //return "value:"
```

EDIT:

```
(char)58 //return: ':'
(int)':' //return: 58
```

Since we want to work with codes and no character we have to pass code to character

another problem to solve is that method "replace" **does not** take "(String x,char y)"

So we pass our character to String this way:

```
String.valueOf((char)58) //this is a String like this ":"
```

Finally we have String from int code, to be replaced.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string as the replacement that happens to be only a single character in length:

```
String original = "words";
String replaced = original.replace("word", "\u0130");
```

The `replaced` instance will be equivalent to "İs".

Note also that, from your question, `'\u0130'` and `(char)130` **are not the same** characters.  The `\u` syntax uses *hexadecimal* and your cast is using *decimal* notation.

Comment: That will work for this particular instance, but if he wants to re-use this code and might not know which character is going to be the replacement, then this fails.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the note about hexadecimal.

Comment: It works if every place the OP wants to use it will always be a character literal.  Since most user- and database-sourced input is going to come in as a String anyway, that assumption is not entirely unlikely.  **If** the replacement is going to be a hardcoded literal, I feel that the Java API-provided method on String is preferable to creating a new method in some utility class.

Comment: You're right. But why didn't you choose to pass in the original string as the first parameter? Won't that always be safe anyway?

Comment: @MatthewC I didn't pass in the original string because _my assumption_ is that OP wants to replace a _portion_ of the original string and not the entire value.  In my example, the _substring_ `"word"` is replaced by a single character, leaving the remaining characters alone.  I'm not going to edit my post at this time because I have nothing to add to it.  Thank you for considering to change your vote; next time, please don't be so quick to downvote other answers that _may be helpful_ even if you don't think they're perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a `"function"` in Java, you can allways create a `method` like this

```
public static String replace (String text, char old, char n){
    return text.replace(old, n);
}
```

Then you can call this `method` as you want

```
String a = replace("ae", 'e', '3');
```

In this case the `method` will return a `String` with `a3` as value, but you can replace not only a `char` by another, you can replace a `String` with multiple characters in the same way

```
public static String replace (String text, String old, String n){
    return text.replace(old, n);
}
```

Then you call this `method` like this

```
String a = replace("aes", "es", "rmy");
```

The result will be a `String` with `army` as value

Comment: This will not replace the entire string. As taken from Oracle Docs: "replace: Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar." I believe he was asking for a method which replaces a String with a character. Not replaces certain characters in a String with a different character.

Comment: I see now that your first bit of code will replace the entire String with a new entire String. However, I believe it looks obfuscated with two of the +"" in it.

Comment: Yes, this will replace all ocurrences of the `char` in the second parameter for the new one in the third parameter, if he wants replace the whole 'String' for a 'char' there's no need for a 'method', only an assignment will work i.e.: `String a='a'+""` :)

Comment: Correct, but what if he wants to do this frequently? He will want to follow good programming practice and create a method to clean up his code.

Comment: Whith the second `method` he can do exactly the same setting as the second parameter the original `String` and a `String` with `lenght` of 1 i.e.: `String a="aes";a=replace(a, a, "e");`, the result will be a `String` with a value of `e`, and with this he will not lose the original functionality of the `method`

Comment: Right, but why wouldn't you use the built in method from Java's API?

Comment: Only for ask the question, for explain the original API with an example and for the encapsulation of the code, this can in a future be replaced for another operation and all ocurrences will be updated, it's the developer who decides :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simply:

```
String orginal = "asdf";
char replacement = 'z';
orginal = original.replace(original, replacement+"");
```

Comment: This method does nothing; the caller still has the _unchanged_ `original` String.

Comment: You're completely correct, I've misplaced my code from other programming languages here :p Its now fixed :)

Comment: And if that's what the OP really wants to do, how is all of that "cleaner" code than simply `original = "" + replacement;` without a helper method?

Comment: That's why I've changed it to.

Comment: Except that `String.replace(String, char)` **does not exist** in the Java API.

Comment: Should have been replacement+"".

Comment: Is there anything special in this ??  Its a simple String replace method.

Comment: It replaces a String with a single character. Something the API doesn't allow for explicitly. Instead using the API, you can only replace a CharSequence with a CharSequence, so you'll have to add +"" to the char to replace a String with it. Something OP most likely did not know and which is why he asked his question.

Answer (score 0):

"String is a sequence of characters"

```
    String s="hello";
    char c='Y';
    System.out.println(s.replace(s, Character.toString(c)));

    Output:
    Y
```

Comment: Guys and girls... `s.replace(s, foo)` is a complicated way of writing `foo`.  Using the String replace method makes sense when used with _substrings_.